# Why do I get a TypeError when using 'useSelector' to access location data in my react-native-maps component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux-toolkit, react-native-maps

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import tw from 'tailwind-react-native-classnames';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectOrigin } from '../slices/navSlice';

const Map = () => {
  const origin = useSelector(selectOrigin);

  return (
    <MapView 
      style={tw`flex-1`}
      mapType="mutedStandard"
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: origin.location.latitude,
        longitude: origin.location.longitude, 
        latitudeDelta: 0.005,
        longitudeDelta: 0.005,
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default Map;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});;
```

This is my code, I'm trying to create an uber clone, but when I run it I receive the following error:
`ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of null`

Here is my navSlice.js for reference.

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  origin: null, 
  destination: null, 
  travelTimeInformation: null,
};

/* Data Layer*/
export const navSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'nav',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setOrigin: (state, action) => {
      state.origin= action.payload;
    },
    setDestination: (state, action) => {
      state.destination= action.payload;
    },
    setTravelTimeInformation: (state, action) => {
      state.travelTimeInformation= action.payload;
    },  
  },
});

export const {
  setOrigin,
  setDestination,
  setTravelTimeInformation
} = navSlice.actions;

// Selectors. Need one for each action

export const selectOrigin = (state) => state.nav.origin;
export const selectDestination = (state) => state.nav.destination;
export const selectTravelTimeInformation = (state) => 
  state.nav.travelTimeInformation;

// Reduce in our store.js file. Initially wrote and now connecting it. 
export default navSlice.reducer;
```

Can someone help me to figure out what could be going wrong here?

I tried to look at the documentation and I'm not sure where I could be going wrong. I also have a working reference and I thought I checked that quite thoroughly but perhaps not - any ideas?

Comment: `origin` is initially `null`, so the error checks out. When and where does the code dispatch the `setOrigin` action to update the state?

Comment: Sorry can you explain that question? I am new to JS - should there be an action to dispatch the setOrigin action to update the state?

Comment: Wait, could it be this?
 
          onPress={(data, details=null) => {
            dispatch(
              setOrigin({
              location: details.geometry.location,
              description: data.description
            }))

            dispatch(setDestination(null));

          }}
          fetchDetails={true}
          returnKeyType={"search"}
          enablePoweredByContainer={false}
          minLength={2}
          query={{
            key: GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY,
            language:"en",
          }}

Comment: Yes, there should be a dispatch of the `setOrigin` action if you want `state.nav.origin` to be a non-null value. The alternative is to seed the state with a non-null value.

Comment: Ah, ok. Does this mean I should change my details from null?

Comment: I've answered an identical question, down to the slice code, previously. No, null is likely a valid initial value, but the UI code should handle this initial condition gracefully. I've voted to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

it seems to be a null ref

```
const initialState={
    origin: null, 
    destination: null, 
    travelTimeInformation: null,
};

export const selectOrigin = (state) => state.nav.origin; // This will be null on first load

// so in your component 

const Map = () => {
    const origin = useSelector(selectOrigin); // This initially will be null
// origin = null
  return (
    <MapView 
        style= {tw`flex-1`}
        mapType = "mutedStandard"
        initialRegion={{
            latitude: origin.location.latitude, // This is where you get the null reff -> null.location.latitude
            longitude: origin.location.longitude, 
            latitudeDelta: 0.005,
            longitudeDelta: 0.005,
          }}     

    />
  );
};
```

If you are using TypeScript I suggest using the `?` and `??` operators

- `?` safe navigation operator
- `??` Nullish coalescing operator

```
origin?.location?.latitude ?? 0 //or the default that you need
```